# Group tables and graphs in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have built a report with several tables and graphs and am looking to group the entire report by a specific field (agency reference #) with a page break between each agency reference # group. I would like for the output to be several pages long with the same report several times, each page with tables and graphs grouped by a specific agency reference #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've got everything you need and just want to group by your **agency reference #** field.

Create a new **List** using the same dataset and group by **agency reference #**. Select the other elements of your report that you want to repeat and drag them into the **Rectangle** that's automatically put in the **List**.

In the **List** Group Properties **Page Break** tab, for the Page Break check **Between Each Instance of Group** to start a new page for each **agency reference #**.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! For anyone else looking through this question, I found this video really helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8EidVXasYg

Answer (score 0):

In Reporting Services, page breaks are within a report. It's not possible to group entire report itself. For your requirement, you can use this as a sub report. Create a new report(main report), insert a tablix and group on agency reference#, and drag the subreport into detail row. Then you can pass the agency reference# as parameter to that subreport so that same report can return different result based on this parameter. After that, you can add page break on group level.